# Creating Lock file in Programs Folder causes exception

Tags: java, locking, file-permissions, h2

I recently decided to use an official installer for my Java application.

The application installs its self in the appropriate folder under the Programs Files.

Inside the bin folder where the jar for my application sits, I have a h2.db file which contains a bunch of information that is read by the application.

When I try running the application in the installed location I get an exception:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: IO Exception: "java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Aurora Game Hub\bin\AuroraDB.lock.db (Access is denied)"; "C:/Program Files (x86)/Aurora Game Hub/bin/AuroraDB.lock.db" [90031-167]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:158)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.convertIOException(DbException.java:315)
        at org.h2.store.fs.FilePathDisk.newOutputStream(FilePathDisk.java:265)
        at org.h2.store.fs.FileUtils.newOutputStream(FileUtils.java:223)
        at org.h2.store.FileLock.save(FileLock.java:197)
        at org.h2.store.FileLock.lockFile(FileLock.java:333)
        at org.h2.store.FileLock.lock(FileLock.java:128)
        at org.h2.engine.Database.open(Database.java:542)
        at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:222)
        at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:217)
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:56)
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:159)
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:138)
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:121)
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:28)
        at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:305)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:110)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:94)
        at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:72)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at aurora.engine.V1.Logic.ASimpleDB.searchAprox(ASimpleDB.java:828)
        at aurora.V1.core.GameSearch.searchGame(GameSearch.java:249)
        at aurora.V1.core.GameSearch.run(GameSearch.java:346)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Aurora Game Hub\bin\AuroraDB.lock.db (Access is denied)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.h2.store.fs.FilePathDisk.newOutputStream(FilePathDisk.java:257)
        ... 22 more
```

It works fine when its not in the Program Files location, as I would have noticed this while developing.

i'm thinking it has something to do with permissions and the lock file not able to be created or something. Is there a way to give/ask explicit permission to create the lock file or can I tell H2 to just not create the lock file?

We've thought about having the static database placed somewhere other then the install location, but since this has to run on Mac and PC and the way the installer is set up it would make things more complicated.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there are no access rights to write to this directory. You need to store the database file in a directory where you do have access rights.

For H2, if you use the database URL `jdbc:h2:~/data/db`, the database is stored relative to the current user home directory. Another alternative is to use an absolute path, for example `jdbc:h2:c:/dir/to/db/file`

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by improved security in windows. You can write only when you have elevated privilages. For example if you start program as 'run as administrator', then it  may able to  write to Program Files area. Then it is not a good idea- see:  [Bypass Windows permission restrictions on program files folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169404/bypass-windows-permission-restrictions-on-program-files-folder)

You should use folder pointed by 'ProgramData'  variable.  or good old user.home area

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X, you can use the known subdirectories of `user.home` cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14233171/230513).

[*Java Web Start*](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) with suitable [permissions](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#web_start) may be an alternative, although I haven't tried it.